# VBA Runtime Error 35600 when removing items from ListView

Tags: vba, listview

I would like to ask for help regarding a Runtime Error 35600 "Index out of bounds".

I am trying to delete all Items from a Multicolumn-ListView that do not match a Combobox-Value. 
However, it seems that during the deletion-process, my code reaches a Point where the listitems-index is smaller than the index of the selected item.

Does anyone know how I can solve that? Here is my take on it:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

Dim i As Integer
Dim strSearch As String

strSearch = Me.ComboBox1

For i = 1 To ListView1.listItems.Count
    If Me.ListView1.listItems(i).SubItems(3) = strSearch Then
        Me.ListView1.listItems(i).Checked = True
    End If
Next i
For i = 1 To ListView1.listItems.Count
    If ListView1.listItems(i).Checked = False Then
        Me.ListView1.listItems.Remove (ListView1.selectedItem.Index)
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try remove them in reverse order (so only for the second loop); I think in basic it would look like:

```
For i = ListView1.listItems.Count To 0 Step -1
```

Probably the counter is not re-evaluated after every loop and thus will be higher than the number of elements causing a too high number (more than the number of list items present resulting in an index out of bounds exception).

Comment: Thank you for your reply! It now works without an Error.

Comment: Unfortunately, using your code makes the function ignore the very first listview-item. Do you have any idea how to fix this in my code?

Comment: Probably to continue to index 0 (forgive me, Basic is long ago for me)

Comment: I've used an older version of commom controls, it worked with count to 1.

Comment: Check if 1 is included or excluded and set the end condition accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
'Removing part
With ListView1
    For i = .ListItems.Count To 1 Step -1
        If Not .ListItems(i).Checked Then
            .ListItems.Remove i
        End If
    Next
End With
```

Comment: What would you define `li` as? I get an Error using your code

Comment: After working around that, now using your code produces a Runtime Error 438 - Object doesn't Support Method at `li.remove li.index`

Comment: See my edit. You can't use a `for each` because the ListItems collection update at the first removal. My bad